# Installing driver for Squirrel sql client on linux to connect to MS sql server

Tags: sql-server, odbc, squirrel-sql

I am trying to connect to MS SQL server database from linux. I can connect with Microsoft SQL server management studio on windows to same. I am trying to use squirrel sql client. I am not sure about the driver I need to use and how to install it.

Answer (score 6):

You want to get the JDBC driver from Microsoft and add it to the Squirrel classpath.

- Download the driver from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11774
- Get the .tar.gz for the 4.0 driver or 4.1 preview.
- Expand the .tar.gz file on your Linux system.
- Open Squirrel SQL
- Click the Drivers tab in the upper left and find the entry for Microsoft MSSQL Server JDBC Driver
- Double click the entry to open the settings for it
- Click the Extra Class Path button
- Click the Add button and select the sqljdbc4.jar or sqljdbc41.jar extracted above
- In the Class Name field, enter `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver`

Edit: adding JDBC URL example
 - The JDBC URL syntax for the Microsoft driver is explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428%28v=sql.110%29.aspx).

The general form of the connection URL is

```
jdbc:sqlserver://[serverName[\instanceName][:portNumber]][;property=value[;property=value]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now when I am tryig to connect to MS SQL server I am getting sql exception that URL is invalid. The URL is        `jdbc:microsoft:mssql://myserver.mydomain.com:1433`    The server to which I am trying to connect needs odbc driver. I will need different(odbc) driver I think. Is that jTDS MSSQL driver ?

Comment: mrk m: I still can't add a MSSQL deriver to my SQuirrelSQL, but WRT to your issue, I think the URL needs to say  `jdbc:sqlserver://<server_name>:1433;databaseName=<db_name>`  ?

Comment: Yes, for example `jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=AdventureWorks;` . You can also add `user=myUsername;password=myPassword;` to include your authentication info.

Comment: Thank you! I spent almost a day in the docs trying to figure this out. Their documentation surely sucks.

Answer (score 1):

its a lot easier to just drop the driver jar into the squirrel lib folder. 
squirrel will find it and use it.